# Lambda docker image won't start if i overwrite entrypoint from lambda console

Tags: docker, aws-lambda

I have this Dockerfile

```
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/opt/"
FROM node:10.13-alpine@sha256:22c8219b21f86dfd7398ce1f62c48a022fecdcf0ad7bf3b0681131bd04a023a2 AS BUILD_IMAGE
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
RUN apk --update add cmake autoconf automake libtool binutils libexecinfo-dev python2 gcc make g++ zlib-dev
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn --frozen-lockfile
RUN npm prune --production
RUN yarn cache clean
RUN npm cache clean --force
FROM node:10.13-alpine@sha256:22c8219b21f86dfd7398ce1f62c48a022fecdcf0ad7bf3b0681131bd04a023a2
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add mongodb-tools fontconfig dumb-init \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE ${FUNCTION_DIR}/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN if [ -f  core/config/local.js ]; then rm core/config/local.js; fi
RUN cp core/config/local.js.aws.readonly core/config/local.js
USER node
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["node", "app.js", "--app=search", "--env=production"]
```

I use this Dockerfile to generate an image (called core-a) that run our application in K8s. I've added some code inside my application to handle the case our application is launched from a lambda function and i've created another Dockerfile like the one above but using custom ENTRYPOINT and CMD setting this values.

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/npx", "aws-lambda-ric" ]
CMD [ "apps/search/index.handler" ]
```

Than i deployed this image called core-b to ecr using core-b as docker image for a lambda function and everything works as expected.
After that i thought that i can use the possibility to overwrite entrypoint and CMD in order to use the same docker image for both environments, so i modified Lambda function's image pointing to core-a and using the entrypoint and cmd values i used in core-b dockerfile, but doing so i get an error

```
Couldn't find valid bootstrap(s): [\"/usr/local/bin/npx\"]
```

Did anyone have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the quotation marks (" ") when entering the override value in this web form.

[image]

These [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-images.html#configuration-images-settings) unfortunately have an ***uncorrect*** note that say to use the quotation marks on each string.